# How to overload operator if it's NOT implemented in library class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've got library class DataForm within within there is `DataForm::Field` class. I'm suppose to use the latest one, but I need `operator ==` to be overloaded. How can I do that without modification of `Field` class and not utilizing inheritance? Is there any way if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a free function:

```
bool operator==( const DataForm::Field& lhs, const DataForm::Field& rhs )
{
    // implement me...
}
```

Comment: Can I use that with the List of DataForm::Field for comparison?

Comment: @elgolondrino Do you mean access to the non-public fields/methods of the class? No. You need to modify the class, otherwise the whole concept of a class would be pointless. See if you can implement your `operator==` by using the public interface of `DataForm::Field`, otherwise there is no other way then modifying the class.

Comment: Actually, I need `operator==` to be overload in order to use method `contains` of `List` template

Comment: @elgolondrino Ah, I see. Well, you can use it everywhere, it's just an `operator==` (which needs a correct implementation) and it does not care where it is used :) Just make sure you at least declare it before you try to use it. The compiler needs the declaration or it will still complain that there is no `operator==`.

Comment: I implemented the following: bool operator ==(const DataForm::Field& first, const DataForm::Field& second) const {
    return (first.key() == second.key()); // key() public method
}

Comment: @elgolondrino Without knowing the classes involved I can't tell if it is correct or not. FWIW, it *looks* OK to me. :)